# How to remove entity from local copy without removing from Linq DB

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a problem in Linq. I am getting all the contents a in table when I query. But I don't want to load certain rows which are marked with some special key `Y`.

So, for this, I'm iterating and removing from my local copy those which are having special key `Y`.

Later on, when I submit changes, I get an error:

`"An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a priceTable and a dataTable. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (P.Id) cannot be set to null."`

Why is it so? How can I alter the contents of a particular entity set without touching some of the rows?

I want the rows that are marked as `Y` not to be returned from the DB. I don't want use them in my c# at runtime.

Comment: > i am getting all the contetns in table when i query. But in that i dont want to load certain rows which are marked as some special key Y - so, why are you loading entire table contents, if you don't need some records? Just don't load them.

Comment: Actually, i have a single table, which interns links to many tables.. so, in this case i am loading the contents based on one condtion and i'm filtering later, so.. how to resolve the eroor any idea?

Comment: Consider researching the `Where()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx

Comment: After loading from DC can't we remove locally?. why does it throws exception.. why should we load only using were()???

Comment: Try doing a ToList() before you remove the extra rows. This should break the db link, by converting the IQueryable result to an IEnuerable result.

Comment: @LLL: you can chain combine several conditions in one `Where` method, you can chain multiple `Where` method calls, you can even build filtering expression dynamically (see @DennisTraub comment). To load items from storage and then to throw them away just because you don't need them, is a wrong way to go.

Comment: @CraigW:here how i am doing Tolist and removing 
foreach (DBData dt in p.Data.ToList())
{           
 if (dt.Delete == "Y") 
 {
 p.Data.Remove(dt);   
        
 }
}

Comment: @CraigW: of course, you're familiar with the difference between `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`, aren't you?

Comment: @LLL p.Data.ToList().Where(dt => dt.Delete != "Y")

Comment: @Dennis yes, just typing on a iPod is a pain so I'm trying to keep it simple ,)

Comment: @CraigW, still i get the same error An attempt was made to remove a relationship between . However, one of the relationship's foreign keys () cannot be set to null. :(

Comment: @LLL Can you show your code where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dennis is correct. If you don't required those records marked as 'Y', then use the where clause and exclude those records. Then you are free to modify and update the records back to the database without any issues.

sample where clause looks like below

```
var data = from p in context.Persons
           where p.Required == "Y"
           select p;
```

Comment: Could you provide some detailing about the exception and the part of the code you are using?